# check if change is of type initial in key value observing swift 3

Tags: swift, key-value-observing

When overriding `observeValue` for keyvalue observing, you can see if the change is new or old by doing change?`[.newKey]` or change?`[.oldKey]`.  However how can i check if there was no change but the change is just the initial value when the observer is first added

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
{
    let newchange = change?[.newKey]
    let oldchange = change?[.oldKey]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nskeyvalueobservingoptions/1413959-initial):

> The change dictionary in the notification will always contain an
>   `new​Key` entry if new is also specified but will never contain an
>   `old​Key` entry. (In an initial notification the current value of the
>   observed property may be old, but it's new to the observer.)

So, if you want to know if a particular change is the initial value, request both `.new` and `.old` when you add the observer, and if there is no `.oldKey` in the change dictionary, that means this is the initial value.

Here's some quick playground code to demonstrate:

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

@objc class Test: NSObject {
    var blah: String? = "Test" {
        willSet {
            self.willChangeValue(forKey: "blah")
        }
        didSet {
            self.didChangeValue(forKey: "blah")
        }
    }
}

var test = Test()

@objc class Observer: NSObject {
    func blah() {
        test.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "blah", options: [.initial, .new, .old], context: nil)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

        if let change = change {
            print(change)
        }
    }
}

var observer = Observer()

observer.blah()

test.blah = "Test2"
test.blah = nil
```

And here's the output:

```
[__C.NSKeyValueChangeKey(_rawValue: new): Test, __C.NSKeyValueChangeKey(_rawValue: kind): 1]
[__C.NSKeyValueChangeKey(_rawValue: new): Test2, __C.NSKeyValueChangeKey(_rawValue: kind): 1, __C.NSKeyValueChangeKey(_rawValue: old): Test]
[__C.NSKeyValueChangeKey(_rawValue: new): <null>, __C.NSKeyValueChangeKey(_rawValue: kind): 1, __C.NSKeyValueChangeKey(_rawValue: old): Test2]
```

Comment: checking if theres an old key.. genius !

Comment: I got exception with the above codes... "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"